# Javascript is partially working and isn't returning an answer

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

My javascript code is partially working, it works on the first name validation, on the Email validation it shows the error for a second but it doesn't return false and the password validation isn't working at all.

```
function validate() {
     var emailOk = validateEmail();
    var fNameOk = validateFirstName();
    var paswOk = validatePassword();
    return fNameOk;
    return paswOk;
    return emailOk;
}

function validatePassword() {
    var name = document.getElementById("psw");
    name.style.borderColor = "";
    document.getElementById("passwordErr").innerText = "";
    if (name.value.length < 7) {
        name.style.borderColor = "red";
        var error = document.getElementById("passwordErr");
        error.innerText = "Password does not fit the criteria.";
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}

function validateFirstName() {
    var name = document.getElementById("F_Name");
    name.style.borderColor = "";
    document.getElementById("fNameErr").innerText = "";
    if (name.value.length == 0) {
        name.style.borderColor = "red";
        var error = document.getElementById("fNameErr");
        error.innerText = "Missing first name.";
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}

function validateEmail() {
    var name = document.getElementById("email");
    name.style.borderColor = "";
    document.getElementById("emailErr").innerText = "";
    var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    if (re.test(name) == true)
        return true;
    else
        var error = document.getElementById("emailErr");
    error.innerText = "Not a vaild email.";
    return false;
}
```

I expect it to stop when you enter a password that is shorter than 7 and for it to show the message. I also expect it to stop when The email is invalid.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You are writing your else statements incorrectly. They should also be opened and closed with curly brackets `else { // code }`.

Comment: @Kobe For else statements that are just one line, that doesnt matter

Comment: Did you look at his code @JamesS? Not all of his functions else statements are one lines

Comment: @kobe Ah Seen the validateEmail function there. My bad

Comment: No problem. You're right though, if/else statements don't need brackets to work with one liners, just not in this case :) @JamesS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing your else statements incorrectly. They should also be opened and closed with curly brackets

```
else { // code }
```

Also, code written after a return statement will not be executed. You will need to return 3 variables at the same time, using an object or array.

```js
function validate() {
  var emailOk = validateEmail();
  var fNameOk = validateFirstName();
  var paswOk = validatePassword();
  console.log(fNameOk, paswOk, emailOk)
  return {
    fNameOk,
    paswOk,
    emailOk
  }
}

function validatePassword() {
  var name = document.getElementById("psw");
  name.style.borderColor = "";
  document.getElementById("passwordErr").innerText = "";
  if (name.value.length < 7) {
    name.style.borderColor = "red";
    var error = document.getElementById("passwordErr");
    error.innerText = "Password does not fit the criteria.";
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function validateFirstName() {
  var name = document.getElementById("F_Name");
  name.style.borderColor = "";
  document.getElementById("fNameErr").innerText = "";
  if (name.value.length == 0) {
    name.style.borderColor = "red";
    var error = document.getElementById("fNameErr");
    error.innerText = "Missing first name.";
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function validateEmail() {
  var name = document.getElementById("email");
  name.style.borderColor = "";
  document.getElementById("emailErr").innerText = "";
  var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
  if (re.test(name) == true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    var error = document.getElementById("emailErr");
    error.innerText = "Not a vaild email.";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="email" placeholder="Email" /><br>
<input id="F_Name" placeholder="First Name" /><br>
<input id="psw" type="password" placeholder="Password" /><br>
<button onclick="validate()">Register</button>
<div id="passwordErr"></div>
<div id="fNameErr"></div>
<div id="emailErr"></div>
```

Comment: Agree, or simply `return fNameOk && paswOk &&emailOk;`

Comment: I agree, I only returned all three bools because I believe that's what OP intended his code to do.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can say, use:

```
return fNameOk && paswOk && emailOk;
```

instead of:

```
 return fNameOk;
 return paswOk;
 return emailOk;
```

Because when you write "return fNameOk;", it will return from the function. The next two lines will never be executed.

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem please provide your full js code (specifically the function that returned fNameOk, passOk, emailOk)